# JsonSerializer not throwing error when using enums C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, enums, model-binding

I have a class with an enum and this class is used as an argument for an endpoint.

Class with Enum

```
public enum ChangeTime
{
   Immediate, Later
}

public class Request
{
    public ChangeTime ChangeTime {get; set; }
}
```

The Endpoint

```
[HttpPost("test")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody]Request request)
```

The Request
{
"currency": "2"
}

When I send this request rather than returning an error as the enum for that value does not exist it sets the ChangeTime variable as Immediate. I have searched the web for this and seen various documents stating that this has been resolved in version 5.0 of .net which rejects enums with undefined values, but version 3.1 model binding succeeds. A work around is I could convert changetime to a string type and then do the conversion, check and throw error manually later on in a service or whatever as part of validation but will incur unnecessary performance penalties on a request that will rejected anyway. Is there a cleaner way around this?

Comment: Can you please confirm that you are using System.Text.Json?